# How to add owner to the folder in MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

[image]I'm trying to **ADD** an owner to folder in MAC OS X.

I tried to use chown, but it does change owner, to another new user. I don't want to change it, I just want to ADD new owner.

Details:

I have folder "test" that owner is Admin user,  I want to add owner Admin2 to that folder, without removing Admin user owner. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

I want the same effect, like adding Users: from UI +.

Comment: Is it even possible with the GUI? Screenshot of it?

Comment: A file or directory can have only one owner.

Comment: Question is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted a file can only have one owner.  What you are looking for is how to set *Access Control Lists* (`ACL`) for file system entries.  These grant or deny any of a set of specific users or group members any of a set of specific permissions to individual files or directories.  See, for example, [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/mac/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/1048) for a quick introduction to ACLs on OS X.  Read the OS X [`chmod` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) (`man chmod`) for the details on managing ACLs via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both users to the same user group.  Then chgrp of the test to this group.  That way multiple users can "own" one file.

Then run

```
$ dscl . list /users
$ dscl . list /groups
```

to find which users belong to which groups.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, what I need is the same effect like in UI